# Change Zotero Bibliography language in Overleaf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, languages, german, zotero

I am using Zotero with Overleaf as follows:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style = authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\selectlanguage{german}
\printbibliography
```

The result looks fine, since I get a German title for my bibliography and the cites work as expected. The only drawback is that text in my bibliography and the cites in my text are in english (e.g. last visited, author 1 and author 2, ...) but I need them to be in German. I tried to use `\usepackage[german]{babel}` but then I get the following error:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

\@ifundefined #1->\expandafter \ifx \csname #1
                                              \endcsname \relax \expandafter...
l.52 ...Init\CurrentOption{captions\CurrentOption}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Is there any other way to change the cite and bibliography language?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example code a small but complete document that can be used to replicate the problem.

Comment: In general `german`+`biblatex` will not cause errors like this. Indeed the following example works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/moewew/8cb38ef87cc256f73f7c288e5a60136e. Note that `german` is *alte Rechtschreibung* for *neue Rechtschreibung* you will need to use `ngerman`. Please post a *full* example document that reproduces the error (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864). Please check that the code you post here reproduces the issue by testing it in a new, empty folder.

Comment: Thank you both for the hint! I am to use a project with a lot of custom style files and I found `\RequirePackage{german}`. After removing this line, I am able to load the ngerman babel package and everything works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly overleaf-related. I'm glad you managed to resolve the issue. If you needed something more, you can also reach directly to us via the contact form at Overleaf.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as *unclear what you are asking* since the question does not contain enough details to properly investigate the issue. Since the OP wrote a self-answer and mentioned they found the solution this should not be a big issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the hints by @siracusa and @moewe I took a deeper look into several custom style files, and I found \RequirePackage{german}. It seems that this causes trouble when including the german babel package. Removing this line solves the error.